# Updating input html field from within an Angular 2 test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, angular, jasmine

I would like to change the value of an input field from within an Angular 2 unit test.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="abc.value" />
```

I can't just change the `ngModel` because `abc` object is private:

```
 private abc: Abc = new Abc();
```

In Angular 2 testing, can I simulate the user typing into the input field so that the `ngModel` will be updated with what the user has typed from within a unit test?

I can grab the `DebugElement` and the `nativeElement` of the input field without a problem. (Just setting a the `value` property on the `nativeElement` of the input field doesn't seem to work as it doesn't update the `ngModel` with what I've set for the value).

Maybe `inputDebugEl.triggerEventHandler` can be called, but I'm not sure what arguments to give it so it will simulate the user having typed a particular string of input.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You're right that you can't just set the input, you also need to dispatch the `'input'` event. Here is a function I wrote earlier this evening to input text:

```
function sendInput(text: string) {
  inputElement.value = text;
  inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  fixture.detectChanges();
  return fixture.whenStable();
}
```

Here `fixture` is the `ComponentFixture` and `inputElement` is the relevant `HTTPInputElement` from the fixture's `nativeElement`. This returns a promise, so you'll probably have to resolve it `sendInput('whatever').then(...)`.

In context: https://github.com/textbook/known-for-web/blob/52c8aec4c2699c2f146a33c07786e1e32891c8b6/src/app/actor/actor.component.spec.ts#L134

---

**Update**:

We had some issues getting this to work in Angular 2.1, it didn't like creating a `new Event(...)`, so instead we did:

```
import { dispatchEvent } from '@angular/platform-browser/testing/browser-util';

...

function sendInput(text: string) {
  inputElement.value = text;
  dispatchEvent(fixture.nativeElement, 'input');
  fixture.detectChanges();
  return fixture.whenStable();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jon. This worked great and the ngModel gets updated with the desired text. You've really saved me a bunch of time with your answer.

Comment: Are there any other gotchas you found when implementing this? I'm trying to get this solution to work, but so far haven't been able to get the model to update. I'm on Angular 2.1.2, so not sure if something broke / changed since this post.

Comment: @NathanG not that I recall. Trying more or fewer change detections and waits for stability may help.

Comment: @NathanG they definitely changed something. I am not able to do anything with that as well. I assume that test zone does not react on the event anymore, this is the only explanation I could come with. Still no solution

Comment: I decided to test this theory out by reverting my project to use the Angular version that @jonrsharpe used for his example, but this did not change the result. So perhaps I am doing something wrong. I'm going to provide some images to my code in hopes someone spots something obviously incorrect:

Comment: TL;DR: Simple unit test that is supposed to set a property on a form, submit it, and check that the event emitter is called with the correct value. The unit test can successfully submit the form, but it does so with an empty value as setting the text input's value does not update the binding correctly.

Unit Test:
http://imgur.com/a/31o0l

Component Class
http://imgur.com/a/y297U

Component Template
http://imgur.com/a/P3wJQ

Comment: @NathanG I've updated with something that's working for us in A2.1

Comment: Unfortunately, switching to dispatchEvent does not seem to change anything in my unit test. Not sure why.

Comment: @dfostic that does seem to be gone in the [latest API docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/); try to dispatch the event on the element, see e.g. https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/blob/8df142c9f3330889e2146f49ab47a097dea32402/src/app/table/table.component.spec.ts#L126

Comment: Waiting for the fixture to be stable did the job for me. It doesn't always seem to be necessary though, in another test a simple `fixture.detectChanges()` was enough to process the event.

Answer (score 21):

The accepted solution didn't quite work for me in Angular 2.4.  The value I had set was not appearing in the (test) UI, even after detectChanges() was called.

The way I got it to work was to set up my test as follows:

```js
describe('TemplateComponent', function () {
  let comp: TemplateComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TemplateComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ FormsModule ],
      declarations: [ TemplateComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TemplateComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should allow us to set a bound input field', fakeAsync(() => {
    setInputValue('#test2', 'Tommy');

    expect(comp.personName).toEqual('Tommy');
  }));

  // must be called from within fakeAsync due to use of tick()
  function setInputValue(selector: string, value: string) {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();

    let input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(selector)).nativeElement;
    input.value = value;
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    tick();
  }
});
```

My `TemplateComponent` component has a property named `personName` in this example, which was the model property I am binding to in my template:

`<input id="test2" type="text" [(ngModel)]="personName" />`

Comment: This answer ended 3 hours of pain for me

Comment: For this to work for me, after calling `setInput`, I had to use a `fixture.whenStable( () => { expect(...) });` block.

Comment: Just a note @redOctober13 that instead of using a `fixture.whenStable()`, you should use a call to `flush()` (in Angular 4.2+) or `tick()` (in earlier versions). `.whenStable()` is designed to be used with `async()`, not `fakeAsync()`.  My team spent hours chasing down odd test behavior (i.e. tests only passing some of the time) when we violated this rule at one point.

Comment: Thanks @paul, good to know. Did you find that documented anywhere?

Comment: @redOctober13 I haven't seen it explicitly documented. But experience has taught my team to avoid it. The whole point of fakeAsync afaik is to enable a synchronous-like test to avoid needing whenStable. The Angular.io site's testing page gives a good summary of the intended uses and they never combine fakeAsync and whenStable. Maybe that's proof enough....

Answer (score 6):

I also had trouble getting jonrsharpe's answer to work with Angular 2.4. I found that the calls to `fixture.detectChanges()` and `fixture.whenStable()` caused the form component to reset. It seems that some initialization function is still pending when the test starts. I solved this by adding extra calls to these methods before each test. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        // ...etc...
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    usernameBox = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[name="username"]'));
    passwordBox = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[type="password"]'));
    loginButton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.btn-primary'));
    formElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('form'));
});

beforeEach(async(() => {
    // The magic sauce!!
    // Because this is in an async wrapper it will automatically wait
    // for the call to whenStable() to complete
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable();
}));

function sendInput(inputElement: any, text: string) {
    inputElement.value = text;
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    return fixture.whenStable();
}

it('should log in correctly', async(() => {

    sendInput(usernameBox.nativeElement, 'User1')
    .then(() => {
        return sendInput(passwordBox.nativeElement, 'Password1')
    }).then(() => {
        formElement.triggerEventHandler('submit', null);
        fixture.detectChanges();

        let spinner = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('img'));
        expect(Helper.isHidden(spinner)).toBeFalsy('Spinner should be visible');

        // ...etc...
    });
}));
```

Comment: Even though I don't use `whenStable`, the _magic sauce_ hint helped me out of my misery: My input field mysteriously remained empty during the test. Adding `async` to `beforeEach(async(() => { ... component = fixture.componentInstance; fixture.detectChanges(); }));` made the field finally be filled.