# Angular 2: Testing [(ngModel)] two way data binding

Tags: events, testing, angular, jasmine

I am trying to test the two way data binding of ngModel with the following code, but when I am running my test I always get: `Expected '' to be 'test@wikitude.com', 'searchQuery property changes after text input'.` Maybe it has something to do with the `searchField.dispatchEvent` part, but so far I couldn't figure out why the test is not changing the textContent of my `displayField`. The project was built with `angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.15`. I tried to follow this [guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#page-object) but so far had no luck. Would be nice if you could help me make my test pass. I am not sure if I have to use `fixture.whenStable()` - as I've seen it used in the answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582707/updating-input-html-field-from-within-an-angular-2-test) - but I don't think that typing text into an input field is an asynchronous activity - I also implemented the `sendInput()` method mentioned in this question, but so far without any success.

This is my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  searchQuery: string;
  active: boolean = false;

  onSubmit(): void {
    this.active = true;
  }
}
```

This is my component template:

```
<input id="name" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" placeholder="customer">
<h2><span>{{searchQuery}}</span></h2>
```

And here are is my spec:

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */

import {TestBed, async, ComponentFixture, tick} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SearchComponent } from './search.component';
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {By} from "@angular/platform-browser";

describe('Component: SearchComponent', () => {
  let component: SearchComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [SearchComponent],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
      ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should bind the search input to the searchQuery variable', () => {   
    const searchInputText: string = 'test@wikitude.com';
    const searchField: HTMLInputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input')).nativeElement;
    const displayField: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('span')).nativeElement;

    searchField.value = searchInputText;

    searchField.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(displayField.textContent).toBe(searchInputText, 'searchQuery property changes after text input');
  });
});
```

**Update:**
I changed my test to the following, which made it pass - as long as the input field is not inside a form tag:

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */

import {TestBed, async, ComponentFixture, tick} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { SearchComponent } from './search.component';
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {By} from "@angular/platform-browser";

describe('Component: SearchComponent', () => {
  let component: SearchComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchComponent>;

  function sendInput(text: string, inputElement: HTMLInputElement) {
    inputElement.value = text;
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    return fixture.whenStable();
  }

  beforeEach(done => {
      declarations: [SearchComponent],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
      ]
    });

    TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SearchComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
      done();
    })
  });

  it('should bind the search input to the searchQuery variable', done => {
    const searchInputText: string = 'test@wikitude.com';
    const searchField: HTMLInputElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#name')).nativeElement;

    sendInput(searchInputText, searchField).then(() => {
      expect(component.searchQuery).toBe(searchInputText);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the updated template:

```
<form>
  <input id="name" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" placeholder="customer" name="name" #name="ngModel">
</form>
<h2><span>{{searchQuery}}</span></h2>
```

The test result I get is: `Expected undefined to be 'test@wikitude.com'.`

Comment: You should `TestBed.compileComponents().then(...)` to make sure the component is correctly initialised. You may also need more waiting (resolving a `.whenStable`) for the component to have updated correctly. See e.g. https://github.com/textbook/known-for-web/blob/master/src/app/actor/actor.component.spec.ts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating input html field from within an Angular 2 test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582707/updating-input-html-field-from-within-an-angular-2-test)

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Thanks this worked - but now when I place the input inside a form tag it doesn't seem to work again. `<input class="form-control" id="customerSearch" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" name="customerSearch">`

Comment: Please [edit] to give a [mcve] then, what does *"doesn't seem to work"* mean? Maybe accept the duplicate and write another question?