# Test that event handler is called when file input receives data

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I have an Angular 4 component that has an `<input>` of type `file`. I want to create a Jasmine test that verifies that the event handler is called when the input field receives a file.

This is the component:

```
<div>
    <input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".xls, .xlsx" style="padding-left: 5px">
</div>
```

This is the event handler:

```
fileChange(event) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if (fileList.length > 0) {
        // save the file to the backend - this behaviour is tested in a different test
    }
}
```

And this is the test case I have so far, cobbled together from various answers on Stackoverflow (e.g. some of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582707/updating-input-html-field-from-within-an-angular-2-test)) which seems to have worked in Angular 2, but not in Angular 4:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('file change event should arrive in handler', () => {
    let input  = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[type=file]')).nativeElement;
    input.value = {name: 'excel'};
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    // check that the event handler has been called
    spyOn(component, 'fileChange');

    expect(component.fileChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The problem is that Karma displays `SecurityError: The operation is insecure.` for the line `input.value = {name: 'excel'};`. Is there another way to manually assign the value of the input field or at least get it to send an event that is handled by `fileChange`?

Comment: Were you ever able to figure this one out? I've been searching everywhere as well and can't seem to find a reliable solve.

Comment: No, I abandoned the test. I just looked into it again (using Angular 5.0.1 by now) and am now stuck assigning the file to the input because the `Value being assigned to HTMLInputElement.files does not implement interface FileList`. No time to debug it further, though. If you like, I can add my current code to the question.

Comment: I'm also having a similar issue with my library [ngx-material-file-input](https://github.com/merlosy/ngx-material-file-input), to reproduce an error with clearing the field (with angular v7), using unit tests. It seems the test engine still have limitations, and there is no actual solution (to my knowledge) to making sure the file is in the native file input, as a `FileList` object (me crying). I tried using `fakeAsync`/`tick` to wait for the DOM to refresh, with no luck. I also tried multiple adding `fixture.detectChanges()` to run another lifecycle check, with no luck again. So I end up havi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there another way to manually assign the value of the input field

You can't assign value to `input[type="file"]` due to security reasons.

> or at least get it to send an event that is handled by fileChange

You can fire `change` event after `spyOn`:

```
spyOn(component, 'fileChange');
input.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
expect(component.fileChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/tfvMw4txqflzUFGrsGRI?p=preview)**

Comment: I can do this much, but it doesn't address how to test all the logic inside the fileChange function such as `const reader = new FileReader();` `const target = <HTMLInputElement>evt.target;` `if (target.files && target.files.length) {const file = target.files[0]; reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => { this.getUploadFormGroup(index, isReq).patchValue({...}); }`  These lines inside the `fileChange` are the things I'm finding most difficult to test, and spying on `fileChange` doesn't allow us in there to test them.  If you can show how to test these, you'll get the bounty.

Comment: I looked again at this.  Because you did technically answer the OP's question, I'll give you the bounty now.  But is there anyone who can answer my question about accessing the lines on the inside?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the code any more so I can't test your answer. But it helped @JeremyMoritz and the Plunkr works so I'll accept your answer nonetheless.

Answer (score -6):

```
describe("A suite is just a function", function() {
  var a;

  it("and so is a spec", function() {
    a = true;

    expect(a).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: hi and welcome to stackockflow, for an answer please provide more information like why your solution works and what was done wrong. Those answers can be found an google etc. and should be clear for everyone. Thanks for contributing and good luck!

Comment: This answer only shows how to write a generic test case with Jasmine. Could you add some details on how to test the event handler on an input element specifically?

Comment: This response is not relevant to the question asked. At least, provide a description of what you're trying to demonstrate with this code sample.