# Angular 4 (karma) Test input value to input filed

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test event which value entering by keyboard. my problem is after set value to the input field, when I print it prints, but when I print it inside the whenStable() it prints empty. I want to know why this value gets reset inside of the Whitstable() function. and how can I fix it?

I have referred: [Updating input html field from within an Angular 2 test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582707/updating-input-html-field-from-within-an-angular-2-test) to write this test case.

```
it('Test input field value. ', async () => {
    const divDescription = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#costDescription'));

    divDescription.nativeElement.value = 'text';
    divDescription.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    console.log('sendInput : ', divDescription.nativeElement.value); // prints 'text'
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      console.log('sendInput : ', divDescription.nativeElement.value); // prints ''
      expect(divDescription.nativeElement.value).toContain('text');
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

Removing WhenStable() make this happens.

```
  it('Test input field value. ', async () => {
      const divDescription = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#costDescription'));
      divDescription.nativeElement.value = 'text';
      divDescription.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(divDescription.nativeElement.value).toContain('text');
  });
```

Comment: The code above works as shown, however should I be seeing this content in the Jasmine runner which is hosting the Angular 7 application.  The field values don't change in browser?

Comment: IMHO, this test actually pointless since all you are doing is testing the value of the thing you just set. A better test would be to ensure the change in the input field is also reflected in your model.

Answer (score 1):

you have to move Change detection call inside wheStable

```
it('Test input field value. ', async () => {
 const divDescription = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#costDescription'));

 divDescription.nativeElement.value = 'text';
 divDescription.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

 console.log('sendInput : ', divDescription.nativeElement.value); // prints 'text'
 fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
  fixture.detectChanges(); // moved inside
  console.log('sendInput : ', divDescription.nativeElement.value); 
  expect(divDescription.nativeElement.value).toContain('text');
 });
});
```

Comment: moving fixture.detectChanges() not worked, but the test case passed when I remove fixture.whenStable(); Thnak you for the reply.