# How to test typing to an input element?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test 'typing' to an input element. My goal is to put some value in the input element, and to see that its binding has the input's value, and also to see the value I entered inside the input element.

The code:

app.component:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <span>My input: </span>
    <input name="name-input" placeholder="Enter name" [(ngModel)]="name" />
  `,
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "";
}
```

The test:

```
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

describe("AppComponent", () => {
  var fixture: any;
  var app: AppComponent;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    app = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it("should create the app", () => {
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it("should type text into input element", () => {
    let inputElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(
      `input[name='name-input']`
    );

    inputElement.value = "someValue";
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(app.name).toBe("someValue");
  });
});
```

After the line:

```
inputElement.value = "someValue";
inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Expected: app.name to equal to "someValue".
Found: app.name equal to empty string: "".

A stackblitz which proves that it doesn't work:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-input-question1q2w3e?

Comment: So what *does* happen? Errors? Test failures? Setting the value then triggering an input event, per https://stackoverflow.com/q/39582707/3001761, still works fine in e.g. https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/blob/main/src/app/table/table.component.spec.ts#L143-L147

Comment: @jonrsharpe test-fails, expected: "someValue", found: "".  Now i added your solution to the stackblitz(i update it). and you can see that the test fails.

Comment: Put a [mre] *in the question*, offsite links should be supplementary.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  But this is already "reproducible example". I tested it in my computer => doesnt work. So i share a stackblitz to prove that its not work and all tests fails. Also update the stackblitz with your and uminder solutions, to prove it.

Comment: *"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."*

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok, i tried again to describe my problem in the Update section.

Comment: That would actually be after `fixture.detectChanges()`, no? You can just say "the test fails with this output: {output}", that's the point of an expectation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry i didnt understand you. In the test the expect is already after fixture.detectChanges()....

Comment: Yes, exactly, but in the question you say "After the line: `inputElement.value =`, at which point you haven't dispatched the event or detected changes and therefore probably *don't* expect it to have been updated.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok, you right. I edited that lines in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is the following code:

```
it("should type text into input element after the view has been done initializing", () => {
  fixture.detectChanges(); // ngOnInit Lifecycle hook is run here

  let inputElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(
    `input[name='name-input']`
  );

  inputElement.value = "someValue";
  inputElement.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));

  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(app.name).toBe("someValue");
});
```

Now, why does this work?
According to the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#synchronous-tests), when you run `fixture.detectChanges()` the first time, the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook is called and this is the key to the error.

You are setting the value outside of `ngOnInit()` however, the lifecycle hook that initializes the view has not been run yet. This means that when you call the `fixture.detectChanges()` the first time it calls the `ngOnInit()` lifecyle hook. This then re-initializes the view to its original state which reverts all changes previously done (like settting the input value).

Kind regards.

Comment: Thank you very much! it works! but i have one more question about it. It passed the test => great! but why i dont see "somevalue" to appear in the input element when the test is finished? (assume that its the only test which running)

Comment: If you test in an app (not on stackblittz) you can put byebugs in the test. You will see that the input field is created, filled with the text and then reset when the test is over. In practice, we don't see the text because the text runs too fast for us to see / browser to consider rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You should dispatch a [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) on the [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) within a [`fakeAsync`](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync) zone.

Your unit test would then look like this:

```
it('#keydown should update app#name', fakeAsync(() => {

  // given
  let inputElement = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(`input[name='name-input']`);
  
  // when
  let event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', { key: 'x' });
  inputElement.dispatchEvent(event);
  tick();

  // then
  expect(app.name).toBe("x");
}));
```

Comment: I copied your code to the stackblitz (i updated it with your code), and its still not work. It has this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'assertPresent' of undefined"