# Angular: Unittest with async input pipe + mock service with HttpClient

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I try to create a unittest for my angular component. The test case should do the following:

1. Manipulate the input with "The"
2. Check if the loading indicator is shown
3. Return a mocked value from the service (which would normaly create a HttpRequest)
4. Check if the loading indicator is hidden
5. Check if the options of the response from the mocked service are shown
6. [optional] Select an option and check the formControl value

First of all my `component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-band',
  templateUrl: './band.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./band.component.scss']
})
export class BandComponent implements OnInit {
  loading?: boolean;

  formControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(3)]);
  filteredOptions: Observable<Band[]> | undefined;

  @Output() onBandChanged = new EventEmitter<Band>();

  constructor(private bandService: BandService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.filteredOptions = this.formControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        tap((value) => { if (value) this.loading = true; }),
        debounceTime(300),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(value => {
          if (!value || value.length < 3) {
            return of([]);
          } else {
            return this.bandService.searchFor(value).pipe(map(value => value.bands))
          }
        }),
        tap(() => this.loading = false),
      );
  }

  getBandName(band: Band): string {
    return band?.name;
  }
}
```

The HTML file:

```
<mat-form-field class="input-full-width" appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Band</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="e. G. Foo Fighters" type="text" [formControl]="formControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <span matSuffix *ngIf="loading">
        <mat-spinner diameter="24"></mat-spinner>
    </span>
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="getBandName">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
            {{option.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>

    <mat-error *ngIf="formControl.hasError('minlength')">
        error message
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here is my current unittest. I was not able to find an example for my usecase. I tried to implement the test, like they did it in the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#more-async-tests). I also tried the `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'))` to set the input value and used the `nativeElement`, inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582707/updating-input-html-field-from-within-an-angular-2-test), neither worked. I am not so familiar with angular unittests. In fact I might not have understood some base concepts or principles.

```
    beforeEach(() => {
        bandService = jasmine.createSpyObj('BandService', ['searchFor']);
        searchForSpy = bandService.searchFor.and.returnValue(asyncData(testBands));

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                BrowserAnimationsModule,
                FormsModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule,
                MatAutocompleteModule,
                MatSnackBarModule,
                MatInputModule,
                MatProgressSpinnerModule
            ],
            providers: [{ provide: BandService, useValue: bandService }],
            declarations: [BandComponent],
        }).compileComponents();


        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BandComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should search for bands starting with "The"', fakeAsync(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        component.ngOnInit();

        tick();
        const input = loader.getHarness(MatInputHarness);
        input.then((input) => {
            input.setValue('The');
            fixture.detectChanges();
            expect(component.loading).withContext('Showing loading indicator').toBeTrue();

            tick(300);
            searchForSpy.and.returnValue(asyncData(testBands));

        }).finally(() => {
            const matOptions = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.mat-option'));
            expect(matOptions).toHaveSize(2);
        });
    }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of unit tests are that they should be small. Of course you can write 1 to 6 as one unit test but it will be confusing. Think of unit tests as I do this, I get that (one action, one reaction).

```
// 1 and 2
it('should show loading spinner if user types in input', fakeAsync(() => {
  // A good thing about using reactive forms is that you don't have to
  // use HTML and events, you can directly use setValue
  // Arrange and Act
  component.formControl.setValue('The');
  fixture.detectChanges();
  // expect
  expect(component.loading).toBeTrue();
  const matSpinner = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-spinner')).nativeElement;
  expect(matSpinner).toBeTruthy();
}));

// 3 and 4
it('should hide the loading spinner once data is retrieved', fakeAsync(() => {
   component.formControl.setValue('The');
   // make 301 ms pass so it gets passed the debounceTime
   tick(301);
   // expectations
   expect(component.loading).toBeFalse();
   const matSpinner = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('mat-spinner')).nativeElement;
  expect(matSpinner).toBeFalsy();
}));

// 5 and 6 (this one might be flaky, I am not sure how the HTML and classes 
// will be displayed
it('should set the options', fakeAsync(() => {
  component.formControl.setValue('The');
   // make 301 ms pass so it gets passed the debounceTime
   tick(301);
   // this may need some modifications
   const matOptions = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.mat-option'));
   expect(matOptions).toHaveSize(2);
}));
```

You don't need to manually call `ngOnInit` since the first `fixture.detectChanges()` after `component =`  calls `ngOnInit` for you and `ngOnInit` only populates an observable stream for you.

[This](https://testing-angular.com/) seems to be a good source for Angular Unit Testing although I haven't read all of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the guide, both was really helpfull.