# javascript: document.getElementById("id").value = 'test' doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

I'm a technical tester and I'm trying to create a javascript that autofill a form with some data so I can automate this process.
The code is very simple:

```
document.getElementById("id1").value = 'test'; 
document.getElementById("id2").value = 'test';
...
```

But in this form there is some Angular code that set some fields mandatory and as far as I see, it uses the class "form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid".
The problem is after I run my javascript in the console it sets the value but when I click on the submit button (that trigger something which will write the data into the DB) it tells me that those fields are mandatory like I didn't actually fill the fields and if for example I manually add a letter in one of the fields, it takes this specific field as "filled" and it works.

For some reason the document.getElementById("id1").value = 'test' doesn't actually set the value in the field.

I hope it's clear, i'm not an expert of it but trying to learn and automate my tests.
Is there something I can do using Javascript because I don't have contact with the Angular developer.

Right now what I have try is editing the class "form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" to "form-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid". It removes the mandatory clause but it's only a visualization thing because still the issue

Thank you in advance

Comment: Frameworks like angular use 2 way databinding, and the validation may well be about the state of the model thinking its filled in rather than the value in the field itself. Your best bet is to talk to the developer!

Comment: Also worth looking at other SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582707/updating-input-html-field-from-within-an-angular-2-test) and referring to answers there. It's a bit dated, but should push you in the right direction.

Comment: In addition to what @Jamiec wrote: Angular uses its own DOM, so the framework decides how and when to update a variable, a text, or everything else. Your way to tryito change the value, *apart from being totally unusual and incorrect if talking about Angular*, is just a dead path.