# Angular Testing: FormControl valueChanges Observable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a text input and I'm listening for the changes.

**component**

```
name = new FormControl('',Validators.required);

ngOnInit() {
  this.data = 'oldvalue';
  this.checkName();
}

checkName() {
  this.name.valueChanges.subscribe(val=>{
     console.log(val);
     this.data= "newvalue"; // updating Value
  });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input name="name" formControlName="name">
```

My Attempt so far:

**component.spec.ts**

```
it('should test data field ', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserComponent);
    const app=fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    const el = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
    el.value ='something';
    dispatchEvent(new Event(el));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(()=>{expect(app.data).toBe('newvalue');
});
```

**Problem:**
Even though input field is populated the code inside subscribe callback is never executed.

It always shows:

> Expected 'oldvalue' to be 'newvalue'.

I tried `setValue()` method too but it did not work. it never goes inside subscribe callback

```
app.name.setValue('vikas');
fixture.detectChanges();
fixture.whenStable().then(()=>{expect(app.data).toBe('newvalue');
```

I referred [Updating input html field from within an Angular 2 test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582707/updating-input-html-field-from-within-an-angular-2-test)
 and [Angular2 Component: Testing form input value change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352337/angular2-component-testing-form-input-value-change) but no luck :(

What am I missing?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

At first glance I think you missed the fact that your FormControl is not connected to input because you're using `FormControlName` directive that takes control name as `@Input`.

If you want to test FormControl then you can consider `FormControlDirective` that takes `FormControl` as `@Input`:

```
<input name="name" [formControl]="name">
                                  ^^^^^
                      `name` is FormControl instance here not string
```

Now we can be sure that whenever we change text in input your `FormControl` will fire changes. But as soon as you write such template angular will ask you for `ReactiveFormsModule` dependency in your test:

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
....

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   imports: [
     ReactiveFormsModule  <=== add this
   ],
   declarations: [TestComponent],
});
```

Now regarding your test.

1) You must tell the `TestBed` to perform data binding by calling `fixture.detectChanges()`:

```
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
fixture.detectChanges(); <== add this
```

2) You should fire change on input correctly:

```
el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

Here's the whole code:

```
it('should display original title', () => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  const el = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
  el.value = 'something';
  el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(app.data).toBe('newvalue');
  });
});
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/IyuuZLnPkR8TpEZJfanY?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanx Mate Worked like a charm :)

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an issue with this approach, please can you see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58355726/angular-jasmine-formcontrol-unit-test-valuechange

Comment: I'm using with the last Angular version and Jest, I had to await for the fixture.whenStable(), then do the assert

Comment: Thank you so much, it really helped.

Comment: for single formcontrol and based on input , it works fine. But if we have multiple formcontrols and all are in same input , how to differentiate each one.