# Test the Value of a Property that is Set in a Subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine to test an Angular app and I'm trying to figure out how to test the value of a property that is set in the `subscribe` call on an Observable within the component. I've put together an example component here just to illustrate the point.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-list',
    templateUrl: './list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent {
    public Result[] Items;


    constructor(private myService: MyService) {
```

this.formControl.valueChanges.pipe(
switchMap(value => myService.getResults(value))
).subscribe(results => this.Items = results);
}
}

In this example, for my test I would be calling `getResults()` from within and I'd test to make sure that `Items` is populated. Since this is not guaranteed to happen immediately, but the `subscribe` logic is entirely within the component, how should I go about awaiting that to make sure I don't get `undefined` when I check the value of `Items`?

EDIT: Here’s a sample of how I’ve looked at testing it so far. Please note I’ve updated how the comment in the code above indicating that the observable is subscribe as a result of a FormControl value change, not just a button click, hence the `detectChanges` below.

```
it(‘should pull results’, () => {
    const componentFixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListComponent);
    const component = componentFixture.componentInstance;
    const myService = TestBed.inject(MyService);
    spyOn(myService, ‘getResults’).and.returnValue(of([myTestItems]));
    component.formControl.setValue(‘abcdefg’);
    componentFixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.Items).toEqual([myTestItems]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `request` method in your test, to get result and status, the point is using `status` to make sure your api work well or not, also you can use `timeout` to getting response.

```
const request = require('request');
const endpoint = 'http://localhost:3000/city';

//get
it('should return 200 response code', function (done) {
    request.get(endpoint, function (error, response) {
        expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(200);
        done();
    });
});
//post
it('should fail on POST', function (done) {
    request.post(endpoint, {json: true, body: {}}, function (error, response) {
        expect(response.statusCode).toEqual(404);
        done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hmm I don't totally understand. In this case aren't I testing the component method specifically? The API method could be tested separately.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are mocking `myService.getResults()`. If it is returning an `of(<IResult[]>)` (which IMO it should be like this), the subscribe will run synchronously and therefore it will run instantaneously.

```
it('should set items on click', () => {
  // click on the element and make sure pullResults() gets called.
  // here we will call it directly
  // Make sure you are mocking myService.getResults() to return an observable in the form 
  // of `of([...])`
  component.pullResults();
  // go ahead and make the assertion right away
  expect(component.Items).toEqual(myTestItems);
});
```

Comment: Yep I’m using `of`, but I oversimplified when transferring the code to the question. The code is actually triggered by FormControl.valueChange, not a button click. I’ve updated the question with this information and added a sample test to work off of, perhaps it’ll make it clearer where my problem is.

Comment: Your test looks fine for me, does it not pass?

Comment: no I get undefined in my `component.Items` so it fails the comparison to my test data.

Comment: I am thinking it never gets into your `subscribe`. Try putting a `console.log` inside of the subscribe to ensure it gets printed. If it doesn't go inside of the subscribe, I think you are facing this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51910630/angular-testing-formcontrol-valuechanges-observable. The answer shows how to do the value changes from the HTML though. Also, try putting the `fixture.detectChanges` before the `setValue` because the first `fixture.detectChanges()` after `createComponent` is when `ngOnInit` runs and maybe you have bindings in your `ngOnInit` that are needed.